# AspNet Core with Angular - Do we need to create duplicates of all entities?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

I'm trying to learn Angular with Aspnet Core and looking at the project created by Visual Studio 2017's default Angular template.

The controller declares a `WeatherForecast` class and returns a `IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>` -

```cs
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> WeatherForecasts()
{
    var rng = new Random();
    return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
    {
        DateFormatted = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index).ToString("d"),
        TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
        Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
    });
}

public class WeatherForecast
{
    public string DateFormatted { get; set; }
    public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }

    public int TemperatureF
    {
        get
        {
            return 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
        }
    }
}
```

And then, the angular component that calls the above code and displays the `IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>` is below -

```
export class FetchDataComponent
{
    public forecasts: WeatherForecast[];

    constructor(http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    http.get<WeatherForecast[]>(baseUrl + 'api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts')
        .subscribe(result =>{ this.forecasts = result; }, error => console.error(error));
}

interface WeatherForecast
{
    dateFormatted: string;
    temperatureC: number;
    temperatureF: number;
    summary: string;
}
```

As you notice, the `WeatherForecast` class is declared twice - once in the .net backend and then again in the angular component!

My question is - When working with AspetCore and Angular, do we always need to declare all entities (or ViewModels, whichever applies) like `WeatherForecast` class twice? If so, it seems like a lot of duplicated effort and probably a violation of DRY?

Comment: Yeah, they are 2 different frameworks. Think about your c# backend as an API Endpoint and your Angular Application as an API Client. Not much you can do. You could probably generate the clientside interfaces with something like `T4`... You will also notice the same of DataAnnotations. You need a server side & client side validation layer. Same for translations and so on. If you want to keep it simple: Use MVC. But there are good reasons to use Angular, but it has major caveats in regards to code duplications...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the choice.  AspNetCore and Angular are 2 differents frameworks that use 2 differents languages (C# and TypeScript).  Even if Visual Studio offers you the ability to create 1 solution for both projects, you should consider your AspNetCore project and your Angular project as 2 separate systems.
Don't forget that your AspNetCore API is able to serve other HTTP clients than your Angular project.